# postgreSQL Create Table Ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

How can I create a table, with a variable to be set within a range

```
CREATE TABLE Range (
    Number integer
);
```

Number should be between 1-9999 as example

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add a `check constraint`:

```
CREATE TABLE Range (
    Number integer,
    check (number between 1 and 9999)
);
```